# How to place `\caption{}` in front of `\begin{longtable}`?

Tags: tables, captions, longtable

Is there any way to place `\caption{}` in front of `\begin{longtable}`? Illustrating with an example, instead of

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{c|c|c|c}
\caption{This is a very nice table}
A & B & A & B \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

I would like to use something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\caption{This is a very nice table}
\begin{longtable}{c|c|c|c}
A & B & A & B \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't show only snippets. Extend your example to a full document which can be compiled directly.

Comment: OK, sorry. I completed my example to a compilable form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `\captionof`. Be aware that page breaks between the caption and the longtable are possible here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}


\begin{document}

\captionof{table}{This is a very nice table}
\begin{longtable}{c|c|c|c}
A & B & A & B \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\addtocounter{table}{-1}

\captionof{table}{This is a very nice table}
\begin{longtable}{c|c|c|c}
A & B & A & B \\ \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]